# Declare a variable in vb.net which is Bit type from SQl database

Tags: sql, vb.net

How to declare or use a value from database which is of bit datatype in vb.net?

dim xyz as boolean
...
..
..
xyz=reader("bitcolumn")

doesn't work for me..

Comment: What kind of database? This should work with SqlServer

Comment: What does "doesn't work fore me" mean?  Have you tried `DirectCast(reader("bitcolumn"), Boolean)` or `CBool(reader("bitcolumn"))`?

Comment: The reader object should have a function that will give you the type returned. You can convert it properly after if you need to. Also, what "doesn't work", you get an error?